# i would like to check 2 table in ASOXScrollTableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

hi i have 2 table and i use pod `ASOXScrollTableViewCell`
when in my table. I know where the information came from the square.

```
if (tableView == myTablePromotion) {
    return 2;
}else if (tableView == myTableBestSeller) {
    return 1;
}
```

and but when in delegate method `horizontalScrollContentsView` `cellForItemAtContentIndexPath` i don't know for check it's not Table
What do I have to do.